# Finding the period-over-period difference across entire dataset

Tags: python, pandas, period

I'm working with a quarterly dataset where I want to return the difference between each period.

```
idx     items            period        metric 1 metric 2
0   Item A          2022-12-31               68      100
1   Item A          2023-06-30               72       99
2   Item A          2023-09-30               88       98
3   Item B          2022-12-31               13      100
4   Item B          2023-06-30               68       90
5   Item B          2023-09-30               50       80
```

i have about 30 metrics, where i want to return the change for all items, period over period. based on the above, i'd like the output to bring back the change for item A for all periods, for every metric.

Any suggestions on the best approach would be much appreciated.

I've tried using the df.diff()

Comment: `df.groupby('items')[['metric1', 'metric2']].diff()`?

Comment: Please provide the exact expected output for clarity